How is this value obtained (through savedstatehandle)
I am going through an android development course, in the course I was instructed to write the following:
class ItemDetailsViewModel(
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    private val itemsRepository: ItemsRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private val itemId: Int = checkNotNull(savedStateHandle[ItemDetailsDestination.itemIdArg])
    
    //...
}

I can't figure out how itemId is obtained and I want to know if anyone has any pointers.
Item Details Destination:
object ItemDetailsDestination : NavigationDestination {
    override val route = "item_details"
    override val titleRes = R.string.item_detail_title
    const val itemIdArg = "itemId"
    val routeWithArgs = "$route/{$itemIdArg}"
}

Initializer:
object AppViewModelProvider {
    val Factory = viewModelFactory {
        //...

        // Initializer for ItemDetailsViewModel
        initializer {
            ItemDetailsViewModel(
                this.createSavedStateHandle(),
                inventoryApplication().container.itemsRepository
            )
        }

        //...
    }
}

I tried using the debugger but it didn't help me that much it just shows that there is a call to:
class SavedStateHandle {
    //...
    
    @MainThread
    operator fun <T> get(key: String): T? {
        return try {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            regular[key] as T?
        } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
            // Instead of failing on ClassCastException, we remove the value from the
            // SavedStateHandle and return null.
            remove<T>(key)
            null
        }
    }

    //...
}


have a look at this: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel/viewmodel-savedstate
